# Google chrome sync

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I logged onto my google chrome account from my work computer and noticed the history from my personal computer as suggested thumbnails. I immediately closed out of chrome. Will this trigger a signal to the network administrator that I was accessing these web sites from my work pc?

Comment: Unless you actually visted the websites on your work pc they should not. But its not clear what you synced exactly. If it was only bookmarks then there is little to worry about. I don't believe you can sync your browsing history.  I suggest you don't use Google Sync while at work.

Comment: Well the site thumbnails came from somewhere... Either google previously cached them in the cloud for you, or chrome took a quick peek at the sites to grab an image.

Comment: it was bookmarks from sites viewed on my other computers. shortcuts to the websites i guess

Comment: @Ramhound Google sync does in fact sync history.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome recover your history, settings and data, such as bookmarks, extensions, etc., didn't access every site in history again, only makes a connection to Google Server to recover your Google Account. The same for using Chrome for Android or iOs.

[Google Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en)